# C# forms Textbox value against database value, sql command or datadapter dataset

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, command

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is the following:-

I have a text box field with a value, I want to check this value against the value in the SQL Server database if there's a match then do a particular task.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT        userID, username , password
FROM           Users
WHERE        (username = textboxUsername.text) AND (password = textboxPassword.text
```

But it doesnt seem to work for me, I think I'm almost doing it correctly?

Also would I be better off using a data set or just a bog stand sql command as there will be other queries to be carried out?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a little on mazzucci's answer:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    con.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT userID, username, password FROM Users WHERE (username = @username) AND (password = @password)");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textboxUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textboxPassword.Text);

    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        //They were the same
    }
}
```

However, consider that whatever you're doing looks fairly dangerous. I think Eric Lippert has made more than a few posts on SO about the dangers of passwords and authentication stuff in general.

Such as this one:
[Does salt need to be random to secure a password hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195692/does-salt-need-to-be-random-to-secure-a-password-hash)

Comment: I also seem to get a return value of -1 regardless of a match or not? Should I not be using the .ExecuteScalar() method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the query using the values from the textboxes.

You can do this with named parameters for example to ensure values are escaped properly:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT        userID, username , password
FROM           Users
WHERE        (username = @username) AND (password = @password)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textboxUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textboxPassword.Text);
...
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this using the SQLCommand Control from the tool box but still having problems